# Ubuntu 20.04 Can't add network printers

Tags: 20.04, printing

Good day.

I'm having some problems with adding network printers.

It just isn't working.

At first i tried doing it via KDE\Gnome settings, then, when it didn't work,

- I accessed http://localhost:631/admin,
- selected my printer (Xerox Altalink c8085) from the list of all detected printers
- checked that the printer's IP address was the one I needed
- then on the next page I selected "Xerox_AltaLink_C8055 fully driverless,cups-filters, 1.28.6 (en)" ( I haven't added any PPD files coz I selected driverless method)
- "Add printer"

And then I got the error message basically saying it failed to add the printer and failed to copy PDD file

In the log I saw green messages

> "cupsd pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn’t open /etc/securetty: No such file
> or directory"

After that I tried using **system-config-printer** but in the end I got

> "non-fatal exception. Traceback: File
> «/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py», line 4259, in
> getNPPPD ppd = cups.PPD(f) RuntimeError: ppdOpenFile failed Continuing
> anyway.."

Am I doing something wrong?

Kind regards.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools to make your question readable.

Comment: Being unable to contact the printer and copy the PDD file sounds more like a network problem than a printing problem. Can you ping the printer? What do you get for `avahi-browse -rt _ipp._tcp`?